# Java getTime() error on netbean

Tags: java, netbeans

I can't run my project, just because of the lines with getTime() / 1000 below. Keep getting errors. It is code for a hotel booking system.

```
private void bookingObjectCreation() {
        booking = new Booking();
        roomsToRoomObjectList(tf_rooms.getText());
        booking.setBookingType((String) combo_reservationType.getSelectedItem());
        booking.setPerson(Integer.parseInt(tf_guestNo.getText()));
        ***booking.setCheckInDateTime(date_checkIn.getDate().getTime() / 1000);***
        booking.setBookingType((String) combo_reservationType.getSelectedItem());
        if (date_checkOut.getDate() != null) {
            ***booking.setCheckOutDateTime(date_checkOut.getDate().getTime() / 1000);***
        }
```

I have been write this hotel management system software for almost a week now, and I only get that same particular error from the control panel.

Comment: can you specify what error you are getting on getTime() method call?

Comment: Does `getDate()` return a `java.util.Date`? Do those setters take a time in seconds? I am guessing you are dividing a time in milliseconds by 1000 to get seconds, but we can't know the types and method signatures if you don't tell us. Or the error you're getting.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for tips on how to ask a question that will be more likely to get you a useful response.

Answer (score 0):

This: `date_checkOut.getDate().getTime() / 1000` will return a double value so you can set it.
I don't know why you are dividing by 1000 but you can solve you problem doing:

```
booking.setCheckOutDateTime(Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000));
```